# Blank page when deploying MEAN.JS on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm trying out Node.JS for the first time using MEAN.JS as a starting point. When testing on localhost, everything looks OK. However, when deploying to https://raichu-com.herokuapp.com/, I get a blank page (the header menu flashes for a moment, then goes away).

I don't see any error in my logs, and the database seems to be connected properly (`users` and `sessions` collections are created). What could probably be the issue here?

I compared local and cloud *Sources*, seems like there's a little difference:

[image]

Also, while irrelevant to the question, it'd be incredibly helpful if you could name me some (other) examples of cloud providers for Node.JS that you think are (more) affordable and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

teamtreehouse also has a good tutorial on getting node to work on Heroku

it lists steps like

specify the version of node in your package.json,

include a Procfile,

etc...

Answer (score 0):

In Heroku var config add

NODE_ENV

development